# Actions not showing in android action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make a dynamic action bar in android, right now I'm trying to make a search in the action bar like this.

http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-searchview@2x.png

However when I click the the search button in the action bar nothing happens.

Here is the menu XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title=""
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

 <item android:id="@+id/action_menu"
      android:title=""
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu"
      android:showAsAction="always" 
      android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Here is the OnCreateOptionsMenu in the Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.    
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);   

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    return true;
}
```

I know the icon I have in the action bar is working because I have this code working without problems

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Search icon is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_menu:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Menu icon is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with this:

```
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Because even when I delete the android.support.v7 jar on the project (I just deleted it to test, I have it back again) I can execute the project without any errors. So maybe the XML file doesn't recognise the android.support.v7 path?

P.S: the action_menu icon doesn't work either.

Comment: for onOptionsItemSelected() try to return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the icon I have in the action bar is working because I have this code working without problems

That is consuming the event, preventing the `SearchView` from working. Please delete both `case` sections of this method, as they are incorrect for both of your menu items.

(and, please use `this`, not `getBaseContext()`, unless you know what `getBaseContext()` does)

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/SearchView) showing the use of `SearchView`.

Comment: Weird how something like that messed up the code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` throws `NullPointerException` at `onCreateOptionsMenu()` with default configuration.

Solved by changing it to `android.widget.SearchView`

The answer by @CommonsWare is valid also. It is more likely to be the correct answer.